# youtube autoplay - prevent starting video again after iframe is moved inside DOM

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have youtube iframe with src `linktovideo?autoplay=1` loaded. 
In firefox it plays automatically sadly in chrome does not. However:

**Problem:**
If I move the iframe to other place in DOM using append - video starts playing over again (does not remain in same state I left it).

What Can I do to prevent that? Example is here https://jsfiddle.net/xwq2ypkv/1/ (play video for a while, then press button to append it inside another div)

**I tried:**
I learned that if iframe is moved inside DOM, it is automatically refreshed (that is the reason it plays again). So I tried altering the src after video is loaded using jquery - this does not work either (after browser detects changes in src, iframe is realoaded again).

Can somebody think of a technique how to prevent playing video after was iframe moved inside DOM? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I'm finding it quite hard to understand the problem - is it that the video autoplays after clicking on the button, or that the video autoplays *from the start* after clicking on the button?

Comment: @user7290573 if there is an iframe with youtube video and src contains autoplay parameter (user might have watched it already), then after moving the iframe inside DOM, video starts to play again. I try to rewrite the question so it is better uderstandable:)

Comment: Hm, are you sure that changing the `src` attribute afterwards doesn't work? I've edited your JSFiddle and this seems to behave correctly, as far as I can tell: https://jsfiddle.net/5sctxuom/1/

Comment: @user7290573 yes im sure. Try to load the video, play it for a while and then change the iframe src a little. Video reloads again.

Comment: So after the video's been through `.appendTo()`, you want it to be back at the same time in the video? If so, you might need to look into using the API to get the current video position.